# How do I break out a DB-9 or DB-25 serial port from a PowerBook-G4 or even a more modern MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, mac, usb, terminal

Essentially, we would like to interface to an external device which conforms to a serial DB-9 type hardware interface (or DB-25, because we have a crossover cable for that), and all we have are Apple notebook computers lying around.

I'm familiar with Sun Microsystems style computers back when we worked in our lab environments and we'd do something like

> tip /dev/term/a

or something like that, to get a Vt-100 style interface to one of our flight computer's serial interface's...  - last time I actually issued such a command was about 15-20 years ago.  :-)

[Added for clarification:]

From a user's point of view, they'd kick off a program (iTerm, possibly) or something like that old SunOS 4.3 program, tip, and then they'd be communicating via some serial interface (UART, probably emulated by a driver) that plugs into a 9-pin connector on an external device, via a simple wire, probably 3 or 4 wires actually doing the communication.

[Added for clarification:]

But the need now exists for our church to talk to some sound equipment, and we are a Mac shop, so...

Any ideas?  Is it possible to get an adapter/driver combination on an later OS-X system to talk out a (say USB-3) port and then act like a Vt-100 terminal over DB-9 connector?

I'm sure I'll get into something like the STTY(1) command to set the terminal flow control characteristics on that device thus abstracting a terminal over a DB-9 with appropriate USB-3 / Thunderbolt adapter/driver.  However, I'm hoping, being a Mac, I won't have to think too hard about such details... :-D

Any ideas for you UNIX gurus out there?

---

We'd actually prefer the DIY approach, and then learn something in the process.

Our precious USB interfaces are at a premium, so utilizing an under-utilized port, say Thunderbolt, or even Firewire-400/800, would work better for us.

Any pointers on wiring up an old serial cable (from a huge surplus box of such things), and then breaking out a serial pair (what, 2 or 3 wires?) from a Firewire already broken out from a Thunderbolt (the least utilized port on our laptop)?

I am fairly competent with a soldering iron and wire-cutters and wire-strippers....  :-)  So, the wiring diagram to break-out Firewire to a serial interface with some pointers on creating a device for such a beast in OS-X, and then setting its terminal characteristics would really serve this chat well.  :-)  That would show what it takes to bridge the gap from pure hardware to pure software, and really lead to a more interesting discussion, IMHO.

But, a canned solution would also work for us, but not one that cost too much.  We are working on a budget funded by faith.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. Do you just want an adapter like this? http://ca.startech.com/Cards-Adapters/Serial-Cards-Adapters/USB-RS232-DB9-Serial-Adapter-Cable~ICUSB232

Comment: The salient problem seems to be contained in the first rambling statement, and answered by @Tyson.  Instead of the extraneous words and photos, something a lot more specific than an *"external device"* would add clarity to the problem.  You are confusing the issue by using a HW term *"breakout" and photo of HW and tools, but also seem unsure about SW terminology.

Comment: The picture of your soldering iron was really helpful to understand the problem. By the way, what is your final requirement? Do you want to control something through the DB9 connectors ? This would be an X-Y problem - where solving X leads to problem Y and in the end we have a new question. Please be specific

Comment: There are so many lowcost pre-made solutions I'm not sure why you want to re-invent the wheel.  Don't assume the "serial" in USB and your old serial cables are the same.  You can't just "make a cable" for this, to understand see [this answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34549/what-are-the-differences-between-usb-and-rs232). As for running out of USB ports, add more with a "USB Hub", also plentiful and low cost.

Comment: If you really want to "roll your own" USB to RS232C adapter I found this article for you http://www.cypress.com/?docID=41719

Comment: @Tyson -- Actually those answers on USB vs RS232 differences are low quality. Both fail to mention that USB is a bus (like PCI or ISA) that carries control, data and power (OK, one does mention "bus" in quotes as if it wasn't a real bus).  USB has one master node and up to 127 slave nodes.  RS232 is a point-to-point com link.

Answer (score 2):

USB to RS232 adapters are cheap.

> Our precious USB interfaces are at a premium

Buy a hub.  They are also cheap.

> so utilizing an under-utilized port, say Thunderbolt, or even Firewire-400/800, would work better for us.

If your system has an Express Card slot you might find an Express Card RS-232 adapter.

The "link layer" of most modern computer interfaces is expected to be controlled by a hardware controller, and the protocols of USB, Firewire, and Thunderbolt are more complex than RS-232.  You can't set the controller aside and read the states of the pins by themselves.  The I/O of a lot of older computers worked like the PC parallel port - if electricity is flowing through a wire, a bit in a register is pulled down to 0, otherwise it floats to 1.  Not anymore - the controller does the link layer stuff and throws data to the CPU via DMA - any registers available are for setup, device enumeration, etc.

So it is *not* as simple as just soldering the pins of your DB-9 cable to Firewire or Thunderbolt pins.

Use a RS-232 to USB adapter and a hub. Velcro strips are great for attaching the hub or adapter to surfaces.

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for to Google is "USB to RS232C".  There are quite a few adapters available.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JanDoggen did you try it? this DOES provide an EXACT answer to the question.  SU is NOT a hardware recommendation site.  Typing what is between the quote into google will lead the OP to 1000's of models to choose from, some of which may be better suited than others, but we can't know without knowing a lot more about the OP's needs.  Once the Op chooses a specif model then he can ask specific questions about getting it to work (if needed), but first he needs an adapter or cable, and again SU is not a specific hardware recommendation site.

Comment: Is the term I'm looking for, to set up my software &^ hardware flow control, "stty"?  Once I have my hardware (per my own selection), what command would you suggest using to speak with our devices?  'echo "help" > /dev/my_special_hardware'?  Or do I also google, "UNIX devices"?

Comment: @BillMcCloskey that actually gets complicated, and may be adapter dependent.  By definition USB doesn't have what used to be known as hardware flow control, some adapters may provide pseudo hardware flow control.  As far as associating the device, you aren't 'adding' a port you're connecting to a port that already exists and changing it's characteristics with a hardware device.